# python os.pipe() to create pipe and open the file descriptor in c

Tags: c, subprocess, pipe, file-descriptor, fdopen

I want to use python to create a pipe `readfd, writefd = os.pipe()`. And then I create a subprocess inside my python script to run some c code where it tries to open the readfd(which is an int say 5) `FILE* fp  = fdopen(readfd, "r");` but it returns a nullptr. Why is this wrong? How can I open the file descriptor in my c code?

Comment: I would recommend using a named pipe, that way you can pull the name from constants file instead of passing file descriptors.

Comment: @Dan I want it to be cross platform. But it will be hard to have named pipe in windows as it don't have os.mkfifo() function.

Comment: Can you simply redirect stdin and stdout?

Comment: @Dan No, since I use stdin and stdout for other purpose.

Comment: Did you check the value of `readfd`? Is t the same in the subrocess as in the python script? What is the error message reported by `fdopen`?

Comment: @DYZ It's 5 in my case. I don't know what's the error message because it simply return NULL as `FILE* fp` is nullptr after that line. I think the problem might because the file descriptor is not real one as it is created by python?

Comment: Please use `perror()` to retrieve the error message.